# how to get count of employees whose name starts with alphabet A and B

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

How can I get a count of employees whose name starts with A or B? The result should look like the table bellow.

```
===========
A   |  B  |
===========
5   |  8  |
-----------
```

Comment: Include some the schema and sample data with results.

Comment: hint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: so far i have done this:
select count(first_name) as M from #employee where first_name like 'A%' 
and another query 
select count(first_name) as P from #employee where first_name like 'B%' i used inner join, union  bt not getting exactly what i am looking for :(

Comment: select count(first_name) as M from #employee where first_name like 'M%' or first_name like 'H%'

Comment: @knkarthick24:is there any way to get the count of names in order of the alphabets so that i can get to know that there are 5 employees whose first name starts with A,3 employees with B 0 employees with C .

Comment: Query which i gave,gives the sum of names starts with A and B rite?

Comment: @knkarthick24 no...your query returns the count of firstname that starts with M or H together.

Comment: @TheProvost: Ques before whose name starts with A and B. Now it changed to A or B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use `CASE`

```
 SELECT 
            SUM(case when first_name like 'A%' then 1 else 0 end) 'A' ,
            SUM(case when first_name like 'B%' then 1 else 0 end) 'B'
            FROM tableName
```

Query basically means add 1 to column A for every first_name that starts with A.

Comment: But if your hoping to get every letter this solution might not be your best choice. But if you only need A and B go ahead and use this. dont forget to mark answer or vote up if this has helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on my understanding.
Below Query will return two columns **1 :Starting Alphabet, 2: Count.**

```
SELECT LEFT(employees, 1) , Count(LEFT(employees, 1)) FROM
TableName GROUP BY LEFT(employees, 1)
```

Comment: +1 for re usability outside the letters 'A' and 'B' only. top keyword will cause an error though but im sure this is just a typo right?

Comment: No need to write Top also in your query.

Comment: is there any way to get the count of names in order of the alphabets so that i can get to know that there are 5 employees whose first name starts with A,3 employees with B 0 employees with C .

Comment: Add an order by LEFT(employees, 1) at the end :)

Comment: oh but you wont get B 0 though

Comment: @TheProvost: I think what nishant is suggesting to get result for all alphabets and if count of aplhabet is zero then le it display as zero. FOr eg 0 employees with C

Comment: SELECT 
            SUM(case when first_name like 'A%' then 1 else 0 end) 'A' ,
            SUM(case when first_name like 'B%' then 1 else 0 end) 'B'
            FROM tableName 
it satisfies condition,, exact answer.. thank u all..

Comment: @nishantnandgaonkar: If you want to get result for all alphabets, you have to write case when for all alphabets.

Comment: @Paresh J yes i know. I only meant that in Veera solution you cant achieve that since this will rely on what letters are present in the table

Comment: Nishant: Even if you already had your answer, you might not be the only one encountering this problem. Some people may have a slightly different need. This is why we are discussing better, more general solutions. SO is like a knowledge base, not a forum.

Comment: @Veera: is this specific to sql-server or is it general SQL?